# How can I access a view property from my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding

I have a ViewModel whose properties are bounded to from the View (XAML file).
I also have a property "StaticText" in the code behind file.

how can I access the property "StaticText" from inside the ViewModel ?

as suggested by Cameron, i've created a dependency property in my View :

```
    String textToTest="I am just testing .";

     public string TextToTest
     {
         get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextToTestProperty); }
         set { this.SetValue(TextToTestProperty, value); }
     }
     public static readonly DependencyProperty TextToTestProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("TextToTest", typeof(string),
         typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

and I've added this to the constructor :

```
         Binding aBinding = new Binding();
         aBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("TextToTest");
         aBinding.Source = viewModel;
         aBinding.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
         this.SetBinding(TextToTestProperty, aBinding);
```

but I get an exception when I run the code.

Comment: You **do not** access the View properties directly from the ViewModel - the VM is not supposed to know about the V. Use a combination of dependency property as suggested by @Cameron and two way binding.

Comment: @Slugster, I can't figure it out. I created a dependency property in the code behind of the V as suggested by Cameron. and in the View constructor, I created a binding as such :                       Binding aBinding = new Binding();
             aBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("TextToTest");
             aBinding.Source = _vm;
             this.SetBinding(TextToTestProperty, aBinding);   but i get an exception when i run my code.

Comment: The exception is because you're setting the property metadata with a default value of 'false', which can't cast to a string. My bad for copying the example from the MSDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By making the property a [Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) you can bind the property in the View to a property in the ViewModel.

```
public string TextToTest
{
    get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextToTestProperty); }
    set { this.SetValue(TextToTestProperty, value); } 
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextToTestProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("TextToTest", typeof(string), 
    typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(""));
```

See [How to: Implement a Dependency Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750428.aspx)

Comment: I can't figure it out. I created a dependency property in the code behind of the V as suggested by Cameron. and in the View constructor, I created a binding as such : Binding aBinding = new Binding(); aBinding.Path = new PropertyPath("TextToTest"); aBinding.Source = _vm; this.SetBinding(TextToTestProperty, aBinding); but i get an exception when i run my code